# How to speed up this MySQL query? Latest messages query

Tags: php, mysql, performance, query-optimization

i need speed up this query for list latest messages. This query running too long (eg. 10 seconds ...)

```
SELECT datas.uid,
       datas.message,
       datas.date,
       CONCAT(conv.first_name, ' ', conv.last_name) AS conversation_name
FROM   (SELECT m.message_id,
               m.message,
               IF (m.from_uid = 1, m.to_uid, m.from_uid) AS uid,
               m.readed,
               m.sended                                  AS `date`
        FROM   users u
               LEFT JOIN messages m
                      ON m.from_uid = u.user_id
        WHERE  m.message_id IN (SELECT MAX(message_id)
                                FROM   messages
                                WHERE  to_uid = 1
                                        OR from_uid = 1
                                GROUP  BY LEAST(from_uid, to_uid),
                                          GREATEST(from_uid, to_uid))) datas
       LEFT JOIN users conv
              ON conv.user_id = datas.uid
ORDER  BY datas.date DESC
LIMIT  5
```

This query use 2 tables (users and messages).
**Table users:**

- user_id (primary, autoincrement)
- login
- pass
- first_name
- last_name
- ....

**Table messages:**

- message_id (primary, autoincrement)
- from_uid (sender message, reference to table users -> user_id)
- to_uid (receiver message, reference to table users -> user_id)
- sended (timestamp)
- message (varchar)

**EDIT**
I added indexes to messages: 
- from_uid
- to_uid
- sended

and this is without efect...

Comment: What indexes do you have on the tables?

Comment: I have no indexes... Only primary keys

Comment: So you expect that people analyze your query to get what you want to do? Describe your goal and add example data and expected output please. You are creatint 2 subselects - never good for performance.

Comment: I need a result like this:

- uid (with user_id conversation)
- message (latest message in conversation)
- conversation_name (with user first name and last name conversation)
- date (latest message in conversation timestamp)

Comment: I added indexes to messages: from_uid, to_uid, sended and this is without efect

Answer (score 0):

Try creating indexed on the id's you're checking.

In this case you might want to create an index on: conv.user_id, datas.uid, m.message_id, messages.to_uid, messages.from_uid, and datas.date might be a good idea as well, since you're sorting on that.

Answer (score 0):

Add indexes on `from_uid` and `to_uid` to speed up the `SELECT MAX(message_id)` subquery. Otherwise, it has to do a full scan of the table.

Answer (score 0):

I would try and remove the sub query(s)

You can clean it up a bit by joining against users twice when getting the user details from te from and to uid. This way the joins can use indexes effectively. Then just use IF in the SELECT to decide which one to return:-

```
SELECT IF (m.from_uid = 1, m.to_uid, m.from_uid) AS uid,
        m.message,
        m.sended AS `date`,
        IF (m.from_uid = 1, CONCAT(to_conv.first_name, ' ', to_conv.last_name), CONCAT(from_conv.first_name, ' ', from_conv.last_name)) AS conversation_name
FROM   users u
LEFT JOIN messages m
ON m.from_uid = u.user_id
LEFT JOIN users to_conv
ON to_conv.user_id = m.to_uid
LEFT JOIN users from_conv
ON from_conv.user_id = m.from_uid
WHERE  m.message_id IN 
(
    SELECT MAX(message_id)
    FROM   messages
    WHERE  to_uid = 1
    OR from_uid = 1
    GROUP  BY LEAST(from_uid, to_uid),
    GREATEST(from_uid, to_uid)
)
ORDER  BY date DESC
LIMIT  5
```

The sub query to check the message id is a bit more difficult to remove. Generally IN performs badly. Might be worth changing it to use EXISTS (although this will require the check in the HAVING clause which might not be good)

```
SELECT IF (m.from_uid = 1, m.to_uid, m.from_uid) AS uid,
        m.message,
        m.sended AS `date`,
        IF (m.from_uid = 1, CONCAT(to_conv.first_name, ' ', to_conv.last_name), CONCAT(from_conv.first_name, ' ', from_conv.last_name)) AS conversation_name
FROM   users u
LEFT JOIN messages m
ON m.from_uid = u.user_id
LEFT JOIN users to_conv
ON to_conv.user_id = m.to_uid
LEFT JOIN users from_conv
ON from_conv.user_id = m.from_uid
WHERE  EXISTS 
(
    SELECT MAX(message_id) AS max_message_id
    FROM   messages
    WHERE  to_uid = 1
    OR from_uid = 1
    GROUP  BY LEAST(from_uid, to_uid), GREATEST(from_uid, to_uid)
    HAVING m.message_id = max_message_id
)
ORDER  BY date DESC
LIMIT  5
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply... Im trying this queries and without effect... I added INDEXes to messages.from_uid AND messages.to_uid with FOREIGN KEY to users.user_id and also without effect :(

Comment: Can you post the actual table declares and a bit of test data please? Then I can try test running it (although will be tomorrow before I get a chance now)